# Terraform not assigning public ip to all instances

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have following terraform code:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet" {
  count  = "3"
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"

  cidr_block              = "${cidrsubnet("${var.vpc_cidr}", 4, count.index)}" #count.index is 3 it creates 3 subnets
  availability_zone       = "${element(var.lst_azs, count.index)}"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
}
```

Above code creates 3 subnets and 3 different instances are attached to these 3 subnets. 
But only 1st instance is getting public ip. 2nd and 3rd are not getting public ip's. 
I have looked online and tried many things but not able to make it work.

VM creation code:

```
resource "aws_instance" "test" {
  instance_type        = "${var.micro}”

  network_interface {
    device_index         = 0
    network_interface_id = "${aws_network_interface.eth0.id}"
  }
}

resource "aws_network_interface" "eth0" {
  private_ips       = 10.0.0.1
  source_dest_check = "true"
  security_groups   = ["${aws_security_group.sg1.id}"]
  subnet_id = "${element(data.aws_subnet_ids.sub1.ids,0)}"
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = ["subnet_id"]
  }
}


resource "aws_subnet" "sub1" {
  count  = 3
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.test1.id}"
  cidr_block              = "${var.security_vpc_cidr_block}, count.index}"
  availability_zone       = "${element(var.lst_azs, count.index)}"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
}



data "aws_subnet_ids" "subnets1" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.test1.id}"
  depends_on = ["aws_subnet.subnets1"]
}
```

Comment: Please show the bits of your code that create our VMs. They also have public IP related configuration.

Comment: Can you please change 

`map_public_ip_on_launch = "true"` to `map_public_ip_on_launch = true` 

as the attribute **map_public_ip_on_launch** expecting boolean instead of string

Comment: The above code only creates 3 subnets with `map_public_ip_on_launch` set to true, which means any instances that is launched in those subnets will get a public IP. Could you provide the code that creates the instances so we can debug further

Comment: @cfelipe Added VM creation code.

Comment: @SajeerNoohukannu Removed quotes from true. Did not make any difference.

Comment: @AndyAldo Added code for VM creation.

Comment: @NoviceMe where is the declaration for `data.aws_subnet_ids.sub1.ids`? and why use `data` for the subnet and not `resource` from the one you created?

Comment: @AndyAldo Added all code, data is used to make sure the main subnet is created first from which all 3 subnets are being created.

Comment: When I run `terraform validate`
```
Error: Reference to undeclared resource

  on test.tf line 33, in data "aws_subnet_ids" "subnets1":
  33:   depends_on = ["aws_subnet.subnets1"]

A managed resource "aws_subnet" "subnets1" has not been declared in the root
module.
```

Could you provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

@NoviceMe

Answer (score 0):

The main issue I see here is that you aren't creating more than 1 instance in the code you provided so only 1 instance is created at all. It receives a public IP address because it is picking up the network interface that is created and associated with a public IP.

Working example in Terraform 0.12.9:

**Main.tf**

```
variable "cidr_blocks" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "List of CIDR Blocks to use in VPC"
}
variable "availability_zones" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "List of AZs to use"
}
variable "create_count" {
  type        = number
  description = "How many resources to create"
  default     = 1
}

resource "aws_instance" "servers" {
  count         = var.create_count
  instance_type = "t3.micro"
  ami           = "ami-047bb4163c506cd98"

  network_interface {
    device_index         = 0
    network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.eth0[count.index].id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = join("-", ["Test", count.index])
  }
}

resource "aws_vpc" "testing" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "testing" {
  count                   = var.create_count
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.testing.id
  cidr_block              = var.cidr_blocks[count.index]
  availability_zone       = var.availability_zones[count.index]
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
}

resource "aws_network_interface" "eth0" {
  count     = var.create_count
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.testing[count.index].id
}

output "instance_public_ips" {
  value = aws_instance.servers.*.public_ip
}
```

**Main.auto.tfvars**

```
cidr_blocks        = ["10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.2.0/24", "10.0.3.0/24"]
availability_zones = ["eu-west-1a", "eu-west-1b", "eu-west-1c"]
create_count       = 3
```

**Output**

```
Apply complete! Resources: 10 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
Releasing state lock. This may take a few moments...

Outputs:

instance_public_ips = [
  "34.244.18.5",
  "52.213.153.230",
  "34.244.69.143",
]
```

Comment: I figured it out, the problem was I was not creating 3 eip's. You still need those to be assigned.